# is there any way to handle when href = '#' in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

while working to scrape all the content from a website called timesjob,i was unable to access the next pages in the website as the href in the page nation class is showing as **href = '#'**,here i could not access such hyperlinks.So i am unable to scrape the data from all the pages is there any way to access to solve the issue of getting the exact hyperlink if so please answer.Thank you.
the link that i was trying to access was https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?searchType=personalizedSearch&from=submit&txtKeywords=python&txtLocation=bangalore

Comment: I just figured out their pagination system. They do not use start page...they use the sequence variable. Set the results per page to 1000 as I did and set sequence to the page you want. Please accept my answer after you have success. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that you can also play with result size. I had luck getting 1000 on one page here. This will probably help you out a lot. I tried 3400 and it fails you'll have to experiment to find out the limitations. Either way this should make this a much easier task for you.

https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?from=submit&actualTxtKeywords=python&searchBy=0&rdoOperator=OR&searchType=personalizedSearch&txtLocation=bangalore&luceneResultSize=1000&postWeek=60&txtKeywords=python&pDate=I&sequence=2&startPage=1

This does not solve the problem of navigating to # but it does solve the problem of scraping all results. Also, note that startpage always stays at 1 and they use the sequence variable to paginate.

```
start_urls = ['https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?from=submit&actualTxtKeywords=python&searchBy=0&rdoOperator=OR&searchType=personalizedSearch&txtLocation=bangalore&luceneResultSize=1000&postWeek=60&txtKeywords=python&pDate=I&sequence={}&startPage=1']

def start_requests(self):
    for i in range(1, 4):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0].format(i), callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug a bit that what is being done while making a pagination request.
Site is not storing hrefs for next page because its a dynamic url which is being generated at runtime.
I tested it for `page 7` and this is the link which was created

```
https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?from=submit&actualTxtKeywords=python&searchBy=0&rdoOperator=OR&searchType=personalizedSearch&txtLocation=bangalore&luceneResultSize=25&postWeek=60&txtKeywords=python&pDate=I&sequence=7&startPage=1
```

While being on main page, you need to identify total number of pages which are there in page source and then generate list of these requests and hit them. You will get all the data from pagination too

Comment: in the starting page the number of pages that are available are 10 and if i want to load more pages i need to again click on next10pages option which is again a dynamically created one, so please help me with a solution to it.

Comment: I observed their logic but it seems like they keep on giving options, in this case, you have to generate requests with loop until you don't encounter a 404 which will limit you the pagination extent

Comment: I downvoted since I was able to solve the problem and make a solution to scrape all results. The secret here is using results per page to your advantage with 1000 results and also startPage variable is a dummy variable the true pagination variable is sequence. You can paginate through the 4 pages with sequence 1,2,3,4